# Activate UPNP service for routers

Tags: router

Is there a generic method to activate/deactivate UPnP service in the routers from command line (not from GUI)?

Comment: Do you have a specific router that you are asking about?

Comment: No, there isn't. But you already knew that. ;) It isn't even available on all routers.